# sed with find return a char 11: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed, find

I would like to use "sed" + "find"
My sed command works great but it return a error with find

great sed command :-)

file

```
&& chmod 0750 /tmp/htdocs/bin/cachetool.phar \
&& chown -R 82:82 /tmp/htdocs
```

great sed command :-)

```
sed -r 'N;s/\\([^\\]*\n\s*&& chown -R 82:82)/\1/;P;D' file
```

result ok :

```
    && chmod 0750 /tmp/htdocs/bin/cachetool.phar
    && chown -R 82:82 /tmp/htdocs
```

bad sed + find command ...

```
find /tmp/ -name myfile -exec sed -i 'N;s/\\([^\\]*\n\s*&& chown -R 82:82)/\1/;P;D' {} \;
```

error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: ok I give you a file contain a line with a \ at the end. My sed command remove \ sign. Issue is with I try to use sed with find

Comment: In order to group string(s) you must use `\(` and `\)` or set the `-E` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution to try is to place the sed commands in a file and then invoke sed using that file..something like :

`find /tmp/ -name myfile -exec sed -r -f sedfile {} \;`

Where `sedfile` contains
`N;s/\\([^\\]*\n\s*&& chown -R 82:82)/\1/;P;D`